# Is it safe to store OAuth credentials in request.session?

Tags: python, django, session, oauth

I need to store OAuth access token in between requests.

The reason is that I have some views that query the API this token is required for.

I am currently doing something similar to this:

```
def store_token(request):
    access_token = some_obtained_access token
    request.session['access_token'] = access token
    return HttpResponse('Token stored')
```

and retrieving the token from the session in the views that query the external API.

Is it safe?

If not, what other approach could I use to store the token in between requests?

Comment: Which backend are you using for session storage?

Comment: The default one - database.

Comment: Then it is as secure as the database and the session token (whatever is less secure).

Comment: Why not send the token each time?

Comment: @jwilleke: I guess this would mean going through the whole OAuth authentication process again?

Comment: @barciewicz To better answer your question. We need to know the purpose of using this `access_token`. Please explain the requirement.

Comment: @xxbinxx: I have some views that query external API with this token. So I am just retrieving the token from session in those views.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not recommended.
There are much better ways to do.
why you need access token in session when you can use **Outh2 authentication** for access token
Please follow this [documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: This will be used if the questioner wants to utilize REST. Good option tho

Comment: @Gurmukh SIngh: Yes, I am using Oauth authentication for obtaining the token. But then I need to store it in between requests that query an external API with this token.

Comment: May I know why do you need a store? Its the consumer responsibility to keep that tokens not the servers

Comment: Oauth authentication? No such thing. https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20NOT%20an%20Authentication%20protocol

Comment: @jwilleke very useful info, it's not an authentication protocol. But the library can be used by questioner, atleast for better coding. Keeping token in session doesn't look right. we don't know the  exact purpose yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the right way. But for your question - "is it safe?", it depends.

If you are using cookie-based sessions, it is not safe. Otherwise, it is safe. The cookie-based sessions will expose the access token into cookies, which can be accessed by browser (extensions).